# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with wxWidgets in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, osx-mountain-lion, wxwidgets, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to build the very first basic `wxWidget`s app in OS X 10.8 with XCode 4.6. I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in window `SetName()`.

Here is the code I used:

```
#include "main.h"
#include <wx/wx.h>

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, -1, wxT("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450, 350));       
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}
```

EDIT after comment:
sorry bout that

here is the chain of error:

```
1) Create(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name);
2) if (!wxTopLevelWindow::Create(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name);
3) if (!wxNonOwnedWindow::Create(parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name))
4) setName(name);
5) m_impl = stringSrc.m_impl;
```

after that it's machine code

Jeff

EDIT2 : just tried with wxWidgets 3.0 and it's the same.

Comment: "i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in window SetName()" -- I can't see no `SetName` in your code.

Comment: I know nothing of wxWidgets, but the "Hello World" example given at the official site says that you must derive a custom frame from `wxFrame` and use that.  Have you tried doing that? http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm

Comment: i've tried to helloWorld from your link and i got the same error but at a different spot : static unsigned long DoStringHash(T *k)

Comment: Can you post a proper (and complete) stacktrace when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a bad, or at least incompatible with your program, build of wxWidgets as you absolutely shouldn't be getting the crash in `wxString` assignment as you seem to do. Plesse rebuild wxWidgets and your own application using exactly the same compiler and compilation options and the problem should just magically disappear.

Comment: ok i'll try to compile wxwidgets from XCode (i was using terminal before)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the terminal (I do all the time), but you need to make sure your project settings are the same. Notably that the same compiler and the C++ standard library (of which Apple helpfully has two now) are used.